# Chess tournament combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

There are $2n$ players in a chess tournament. The first round consists of pairing the players to
participate in $n$ matches with every player playing one match. In terms of $n,$ how many ways can
this pairing take place?

The first pair of people can be chosen from $\binom{2n}{2}.$

Since we chose the first pair, the next pair will be chosen from an amount of $\binom{2n-2}{2}.$

This pattern continues till $\binom{2}{2}$ which is for the $n$th pair.

Hence, the pairings will be $$\binom{2n}{2}\cdot\binom{2n-2}{2}\cdot...\cdot\binom{2}{2}.$$

Dividing by $n!$ gets the ways $2n$ people can be chosen to play $n$ games.

How do I simplify this?

Comment: I'm stuck on finding a simpler form/simplifying that mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much neater way is to note that if the players are arbitrarily ordered, the first player has $2n-1$ possible matchups, the second unmatched player has $2n-3$ and so on. Thus there are $(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots(3)(1)$ possible matchups, which is usually denoted as $(2n-1)!!$ using the *double factorial*.

Answer (score 1):

That will be $\frac{2n!}{2^{n}n!}$

Comment: Could you give an explanation on how you simplified it to that?

Comment: @Bongocat just use definition $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and cancel out terms

Answer (score 0):

After solving the problem (which you did correctly), you could  have simplified by observing that

$$ \binom{2n}{2} = \frac{2n(2n-1)}{2} = n(2n-1),$$
$$ \binom{2n-2}{2} = \frac{(2n-2)(2n-1)}{2} = (n-1)(2n-1),$$

and in general
$$ \binom{2k}{2} = \frac{2k(2k-1)}{2} = k(2k-1).$$

So the numerator you computed is

$$ n(2n-1)\cdot(n-1)(2n-3)\cdot(n-2)(2n-5)\cdots3(5)\cdot2(3)\cdot1(1).$$

In the denominator you have $n!$ canceling the terms
$n,$ $n-1,$ $n-2,\ldots,$ $3,2,1$ in the numerator, leaving
$$ (2n-1)\cdot(2n-3)\cdot(2n-5)\cdots(5)\cdot(3)\cdot(1),$$

which is the same formula you have seen derived in another way already.